# Linear gradient not being displayed with full color-stop

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to add a linear-gradient on an element with a full color-stop when it reaches 50% of the element but nothing seems to be displayed.

I created an example in codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwaGQW

This is the code I am using for adding the background image:

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, color-stop(50%, #94A14E), color-stop(50%, #C5C5C5));
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet, correct syntax is `'linear-gradient(to right,#94A14E 50%, #C5C5C5)'`

```js
(function() {
  let element = document.querySelector('.ceva');
  
  element.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right,#94A14E 50%, #C5C5C5)'
})()
```

```css
.ceva
{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="ceva"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah your gradient syntax is wrong: check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Should be something like:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#94A14E 50%, #C5C5C5 50%);
```

Comment: 50% after the second color would result in 2 colors being split entirely on either side of the page. right?

Comment: @UlugToprak Yep

Comment: i don't think this is the desired outcome, it seems like he used the `50%` after before `#C5C5C5` because he was trying to implement `color-stop` syntax